# populate drop down list according to choice in previous drop down list

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am a new developer and I am trying to populate a drop down list as the result of what was chosen in a previous drop down list. I am stuck and would appreciate a full answer, I think I need a script somewhere but am not sure where to put it, and where to include the script tag.

Controller:

```
 //// GET: TmplRisks/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.TRisks = db.TmplRisks.ToList();
            ViewBag.CategoryL1 = new SelectList(db.CatRiskLevel1Categories, "RiskLevel1CategoryID", "Level1");
            //ViewBag.CategoryL2 = new SelectList(db.CatRiskLevel2Categories, "RiskLevel2CategoryID", "Level2");
            var model = new TmplRisk();
            return View(model);
        }

        // POST: TmplRisks/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "TRiskID,Name,Description,Source,IsKeyRisk,CategoryL1,CategoryL2,Active")] TmplRisk model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.TmplRisks.Add(model);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Create");
            }

            ViewBag.TRisks = db.TmplRisks.ToList();
            ViewBag.CategoryL1 = new SelectList(db.CatRiskLevel1Categories, "RiskLevel1CategoryID", "Level1", model.CategoryL1);
            //ViewBag.CategoryL2 = new SelectList(db.CatRiskLevel2Categories, "RiskLevel2CategoryID", "Level2", tmplRisk.CategoryL2);
            return View(model);
        }


        public ActionResult FillCategoryLevel2(int category1)
        {
            var categoryLevel2 = db.CatRiskLevel2Categories.Where(c => c.CatRL1ID == category1);
            return Json(categoryLevel2, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

where do i call my FillCategoryLevel2() from?

View:

```
@model RiAct._02.Models.TmplRisk

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/FillCategoryLevel2.js"></script>
</head>
<div class="container col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
        @Html.Partial("List", (IEnumerable<RiAct._02.Models.TmplRisk>)ViewBag.TRisks)
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
                <script>
                function FillCategoryLevel2() {
                var category1Id = $('#CategoryL1').val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/TmplRisks/Create',
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    data: { CategoryL1: category1Id },
                    success: function (categoryL2) {
                        $("#CategoryL2").html(""); // clear before appending new list
                        $.each(categoryL2, function (i, CategoryL2) {
                            $("#CategoryL2").append(
                                $('<option></option>').val(CategoryL2.RiskLevel2CategoryID).html(CategoryL2.Level2));
                        });
                    }
                });
                }
                </script>


            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="panel panel-default list-panel" id="list-panel">
                    <div class="panel-heading list-panel-heading">
                        <div class="panel-title list-panel-title">
                            New Risk Template
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="form-horizontal text-center">
                            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            <div class="form-group col-md-offset-1">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group col-md-offset-1">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group col-md-offset-1">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Source, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Source, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Source, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>



                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CategoryL1, new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                                <div class="col-md-9">
                                    @Html.DropDownList("CategoryL1", null, "Select One", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "FillCategoryLevel2()" })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CategoryL1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CategoryL2, new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                                <div class="col-md-9">
                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CategoryL2,
                                    new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "RislLevel2CategoryID", "Level2"),
                                     "Select one",
                                     new { @class = "form-control" })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CategoryL2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsKeyRisk, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                                <div class="col-md-9 text-left">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsKeyRisk)
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsKeyRisk, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Active, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                                <div class="col-md-9 text-left">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Active)
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Active, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="btn-group pull-right">
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Reset", "Create", null, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
                                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling the `Create` method from your ajax call when you should be calling `FillCategoryLevel2` ?

Comment: Suggest you study the code in [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) to understand how to correctly implement cascading dropdownlists

Comment: I'm not sure where to call FillCategoryLevel2 from, and where to store this method